# A plug-in doesn't work after installing on VIm

Tags: neovim

I was trying to install a plug-in "vim-surround" but it doesn't work after executing the following commands on my terminal.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/tpope/start 
$ cd ~/.vim/pack/tpope/start
$ git clone https://tpope.io/vim/surround.git
$ vim -u NONE -c "helptags surround/doc" -c q
```

I'm new to Vim and I was wondering if there's more to just typing those commands on the terminal? Do I have to add some lines on the config file to make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well… Vim **or** Neovim? They have different config files and directories and those instructions are specifically for Vim.

Comment: @romainl Oh, you got a good point! Shoot....I am on Neovim. Do I have to undo what I just did? How can I change it to Neovim version?

Comment: You can leave things the way they are (they are harmless) and redo the commands with the correct *Neovim* paths and all. I would suggest you take some time to learn a bit more of it before installing plugins.

Comment: lol, you even got the binary name wrong. The neovim bianry is `nvim`, not `vim`. Dude, get the basic right before doing more advanced stuff.